# Check whether all lines of file occur in different file

Tags: text-processing

I got two files: file1 with about 10 000 lines and file2 with a few hundred lines. I want to check whether all lines of file2 occur in file1. That is: ∀ line ℓ ∈ file2 : ℓ ∈ file1

Should anyone not know what these symbols mean or what "check whether all lines of file2 occur in file1" means: Several equivalent lines in either files don't influence whether the check returns that the files meet the requirement or don't.

How do I do this?

Comment: May those files have duplicated lines? If `file2` contains 2 lines `A`, do you need `file1` to contain at least 2 lines `A`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas All lines (in both files) are guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @UTF-8 That would be an important detail to edit into your question.

Comment: @DavidZ Not anymore as the existing answers don't rely on that guarantee. So by editing the question now, I'd reduce the apparent scope of the answers.

Comment: @UTF-8 I suppose so, although the question is a little ambiguous without it, e.g. if a given line occurs 5 times in file2, does that line also have to occur 5 times in file1 (as opposed to only once)? If you had that requirement, it doesn't look like any of the existing answers would work, so I'd suggest at least editing in something that makes it clear that that's not what you mean.

Comment: @DavidZ Added clarification.

Comment: @DavidZ I now added even more clarification for those who don't know what math symbols mean.

Comment: Hm, well... thanks for taking my feedback into account, but as I read the current version of the question, I can't help but feel that it's harder for a new reader to understand than it was before. The kind of change I was thinking of could be as little as (starting from the previous revision and) adding a sentence like "If a line occurs multiple times in file2, it's enough that it occurs once in file1." (just for example)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396731/check-if-file-is-contained-in-another-file

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
comm -13 <(sort -u file_1) <(sort -u file_2)
```

This command will output lines unique to `file_2`. So, if output is empty, then all `file_2` lines are contained in the `file_1`.

**From comm's man:**

> ```
>    With  no  options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
>    lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
>    column three contains lines common to both files.
>
>    -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
>
>    -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
>
>    -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
> ```

Comment: @don_crissti True. Fixed: the `-u` option added to the `sort` command. Now, only unique lines are left in both sorted files.

Comment: Awesomely simply solution! Is this syntax applicable to any program which expects files? I always thought the `<` piped into stdin. Does the bracket term change this?

Comment: @UTF-8 It is called **Process substitution**. You can read [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) about it. And yes, it behaves like a temporary file, so it can be used instead of real files in any programs, which expects files.

Comment: If this is something you do often, you might want to store `file_1` in presorted form. Saves both typing and time.

Comment: @minimax Good comment except for the "any". Process substitution, while wonderful, cannot be used in all cases, because the resulting "files" are streams and not real files. This means that they are not "seekable" like a normal file is, and can only be used when the program reads the file normally from the beginning, and not when the program uses some file-only functionality such as seeking to a specific point or rewinding to start over from the beginning. Happily, most programs simply read() their files, and so process substitution works with most programs, but not "any" programs.

Answer (score 8):

```
[ $(grep -cxFf file2 <(sort -u file1)) = $(sort -u file2 | wc -l) ] && 
  echo all there || 
  echo some missing
```

If the number of matches from file2 in (the unique lines of) file1 is the same as the number of unique lines in file2, then they're all there; otherwise, they aren't.

Answer (score 6):

Using GNU `awk` where it does support specific `length(array)` feature (and some other `awk` implementation which may can support) and not required if files are sorted.

```bsh
gawk 'FNR==NR{seen[$0];next} ($0 in seen){delete seen[$0]};
    END{print (!length(seen))?"Matched":"Not Matched"}' file2 file1
```

This is reading *file2* into an array called `seen` with the key as entire line of *file2*.

Then read *file1* and for each line if matched with lines in array seen then delete that key.

At the end if the array was empty means all lines in *file2* exist in *file1* and will print *`Matched`*, otherwise will display *`Not Matched`*.

---

For the compatibility in all `awk` implementations.

```bsh
awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$0];next} ($0 in seen){delete seen[$0]};
    END{for(x in seen);print (!x)?"Matched":"Not Matched"}' file2 file1
```

To ignoring empty lines/or lines with whitespaces only if in *file2*, you would need to add `NF` to the condition in `NR==FNR && NF {...` to skip reading them into the array.

Comment: `length(array)` is gawk-only AFAIK; it definitely isn't POSIX.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Correct, I have updated my answer. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using `comm` you can find lines that are common in both files.

```
comm -12 file1 file2
```

Have a look at [`man comm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) for more details

Comment: Correct it's returning common lines in both files, but this doesn't provide an answer to the OP's Q where if you had a line in file2 which doesn't exit in file1, so all lines of file2 doesn't exist in file1.

Comment: files should be sorted. From man "`comm` - compare two sorted files line by line".

Comment: @MiniMax is right. This doesn't work. The other answer utilizing `comm` contains a solution which isn't obviously incorrect. When I run your command, I get warnings that the files aren't in sorted order and lots of lines which definitely are in both files.

Answer (score 3):

```
diff -q <(sort -u file2) <(grep -Fxf file2 file1 | sort -u)
```

will produce no output if `file1` contains *all the lines* in `file2` and exit with status `0`, otherwise it will print something like

```
Files /proc/self/fd/11 and /proc/self/fd/12 differ
```

and exit with status `1`

Answer (score 2):

Use a Python program:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def open_arg(path):
    return sys.stdin if path == '-' else open(path)

def strip_linebreak(s):
    return s[:-1] if s.endswith('\n') else s

with open_arg(sys.argv[1]) as pattern_file:
    patterns = set(map(strip_linebreak, pattern_file))

with open_arg(sys.argv[2]) as dataset_file:
    for l in map(strip_linebreak, dataset_file):
        patterns.remove(l)
        if not patterns:
            break

sys.exit(int(bool(patterns)))
```

Usage:

```
python3 contains-all.py file2 file1
```

The program exit status indicates whether all patterns of file 2 were matched:

- 0 (success) means all patterns were matched.
- 1 (failure) means some patterns weren't matched.

To query the exit status in a shell (script) you can either use the `$?` special variable or other expressions that evaluate command exit status, e. g. short circuit operators `&&` and `||` and conditional expressions like `if` or `while`. Example:

```sh
if python3 compare-all.py file2 file1 && some-other --condition; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`combine` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) will show you all the lines in `file2` that aren't in `file1` with:

```
combine file2 not file1
```

Then you can count the number of lines by piping it to `wc -l`, like:

```
if [ $(combine file2 not file1 | wc -l) != 0 ]; then
  echo "lines missing"
else
  echo "You're fine"
fi
```