# Linux: difference between "/usr/bin/env" and "/usr/bin/strings /proc/$$/environ"

Tags: linux, environment-variables, proc

I am learning about linux
and I have a question that I have encountered in one of the books I read:

> The following are two different ways to print out environment variables. Please describe their differences:
>
> ```
> $ /usr/bin/env
> $ /usr/bin/strings /proc/$$/environ
> ```

I searched both in Google and in the book, and everything I found suggests that both methods prints out the environment variables of the current process, but when I try to run them, I see differences but I don't know why.

using the following commands:

```
/usr/bin/env > file1 

/usr/bin/strings /proc/$$/environ > file2
```

Now I'm want to see some difference between the files, so i sort the lines
and check whether a line in file1 isn't appear in file2 and vice versa

The result of `comm -13 <(sort -u file1) <(sort -u file2)`
is

[image]

and when I use `comm -13 <(sort -u file2) <(sort -u file1)`
[image]

(source for the command: [Check whether all lines of file occur in different file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397747/check-whether-all-lines-of-file-occur-in-different-file))

Comment: `/proc/$$/environ` is null-separated: `xargs -0 -L1 < /proc/$$/environ` will produce the same content as `env`, perhaps in a different order.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show an example of how they are different.

Comment: I edited an example of what I currently see in the cmd

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `proc(5)` manual on a current Ubuntu system, describing `/proc/[pid]/environ`:

> This file contains the initial environment that was set when the currently executing program was started via `execve(2)`.

Since `$$` is the PID of the current shell, `/proc/$$/environ` would contain the environment of the current shell, the way it look when the shell started before any of the shell's initialisation files were executed.

The `env` utility would output the environment the way it currently looks.  This may differ if your shell's initialisation scripts modified the environment or if you have manually exported new shell variables into the environment or unset environment variables.

From the information that you show, we can see that the current working directory, `PWD`, was `/home/seed` when the shell started, but that you moved to `/home/seed/Desktop/Lab1` to run the `env` command (by first moving to `/home/seed/Desktop`, as indicated by `OLDPWD`).  We can also see that your shell's initialisation files set `LESSOPEN`, `LESSCLOSE`, and `LS_COLORS` and modified the `PATH` variable.